# Super + D keyboard shortcut does not hide desktop in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I was able to show/hide desktop using Keyboard shortcut Super+D in Ubuntu 14.04LTS Trusty Tahr, But I am not able to perform the same after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenian.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you push and hold super key, you should see tab with default keyboard shortcuts. And here you can see shortcut `Ctrl+Super+D` with is that one you are looking for.

And if you want set your own, you can do this in keyboard settings.

[image]

Comment: This shortcut is not displayed but it works by default.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have it displayed.. :)

Comment: But I don't for some mysterious reason. I mean press and hold Super.

Comment: Interesting. I have it as 3. item in Windows section, down on the left.

Comment: My 3rd item there is Ctrl+Super+W. Maybe it is a translation issue. I have a non-English interface.

Comment: You don't see keyboard shortcuts tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47901/discussion-between-bluemancz-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+Super+D in Ubuntu 16.04.